# Webpack dev server to write bundle.js for every edit

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using reactJs with webpack in my Java (Spring boot) project.
I have configured the webpack server to serve the bundle.js file from local folder so I can use it inside my tomcat server.
I used the "WriteFilePlugin" to write the file to HD, but **the problem is : when I run "npm start" the file only generated one time and not updated after each edit to Js files.**  Please let me know how to fix this issue? .

following my webpack dev server config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import WriteFilePlugin from 'write-file-webpack-plugin';
import DashboardPlugin from 'webpack-dashboard/plugin';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  noInfo: true,
  entry: [
    './src/webpack-public-path',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?http://localhost:8080/',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}../../../../target/classes/public`,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin({ port: 3333 }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "React": "react",
    })

    , new WriteFilePlugin({force:true})

  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  },
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using hot module replacement, I believe the [write-file-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin) plugin was created for this very purpose.